# ¿Cómo enviar un archivo a traves de Axios?

Tags: javascript, axios

Quiero enviar un archivo a traves de una petición Post, pero lo que necesito es usar la URL del archivo. Es decir, yo del archivo lo que tengo es la ULR, no tengo el archivo a traves de input.

```
  const formData = new FormData();

  formData.append('file', 'C:/Users/ignacio/Downloads/archivo.xlsx');

  await axios.post(url, formData, { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"})
```

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrarnos el código que has intentado?

Comment: @HéctorM. ahi agregue el codigo que estoy intentando.

Answer (score 4):

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de como podrías enviarlo al servidor. Inicialmente no se pone una dirección en un `formData`.

El `archivo` lo podrías agarrar de una variable tipo

```
const archivoInput = document.getElementById('input-archivo');
const archivo = archivoInput.files[0];
```

```
// Crear una instancia de FormData
const formData = new FormData();

// Agregar el archivo al FormData
formData.append('archivo', archivo);

// Enviar la solicitud POST con Axios
axios.post('/url-del-servidor', formData, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  }
}).then(respuesta => {
  console.log(respuesta);
}).catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Okey, pero como tendría que obtenerlo desde mi computadora y no desde un input?

Comment: Se me hace poco ordinario hacerlo como tu quieres pero tal vez con `fetch` se pueda lograr...

Comment: Es que no estoy haciendo una pagina web. Solamente es un script ejecutado desde mi local y necesito enviar un archivo que esta almacenado en mi computadora, sin importa el poco sentido que tenga jajaajaj
No creo poder hacer un fetch a un directorio de mi computadora.

Answer (score 0):

Según la [documentación](https://axios-http.com/docs/multipart), eso sería algo como

```
import {fileFromPath} from 'formdata-node/file-from-path'

...

formData.append('file', await fileFromPath('C:/foo/bar.jpg'));

axios.post(url, formData, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
})
```

Con eso, la ejecución va a armar el blob pa adjuntar.

Comment: Cual sería la libreria a instalar por npm?

Comment: @IgnacioWolf está indicada en el fragmento de código y en la documentación enlazada

Comment: La libreria file-from-path no la encontre pero existe files-from-path.
La use pero me genera error con la dirección del archivo, me dice que no existe y literal estoy copiando y pegando la ruta.
Ejemplo: C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\archivo.xlsx
Pero cuando logeo el error dice que el path es C:\\Users\\Admin\\Downloads\\C